# How can I get rid of "Update to recommended settings" warning?

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos

I'm porting an iOS game to tvOS (Unity game). I have this annoying warning that I can't get rid of. Whenever I click on "Update to recommended settings" it pops up a window saying "Project settings are valid". The warning's still there.

[image]

(Never mind the other warnings :D)

Things I've tried: Clean>Rebuild the project, restart Xcode

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the target and build folder with `Cmd + K` and `Cmd + Alt + Shift + K`?

Comment: yes that's the first thing I tried, sorry will update the question

Comment: have you tried to clean the project? 1) backup everything, 2) quit xcode, 3) right click on the xcodeproj file and select show package contents 4) delete everything inside except for `project.pbxproj`. Open xcode and try to open your project again. See if the problem vanished.

Comment: That is warning and won't affect your current build. However, it is recommended to update your pods to recommended settings. You can do this by simply clicking on warning. A pop-up alert will show-up. Now click on Perform Changes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found that closing the project, quitting Xcode, restarting Xcode and re-opening the project worked for me. Xcode 8.1 (8B62)

Comment: worked for me as well 

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cocoapods and the warnings are related to your Pods, updating to the latest version of Cocoapods before you update your pods can resolve these recommended settings warnings.

**1. Upgrade to the latest version of Cocoapods**

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Or, if you use Homebrew:

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

Or, if you use Bundler:

```
bundle update cocoapods
```

**2. Update your pods**

```
pod update
```